# My SQl list unmatched rows in joins

Tags: mysql

i am new to mysql, i am writing a program where there are 3 tables
1. property_types (id, typename)
   Data : (1, houses) (2, shops) (3, restaurants)...
2. properties (id, propertyname, typeid)
   Data : (1, houses-1, 1) (2, houses-1, 1) (3, shop-1, 2)...
3. properties_rent (id, propertyid, amount, year)
   Data : (1, 1, 500.00, 2010) (2, 1, 500.00, 2011) (3, 2, 700.00, 2010)...

I need to list ALL properties of a kind (property type eg: shops) who haven't paid the rent for 2012, so basically if a property (house-1) have paid rent for 2010 & 2011 but not 2012 it should be listed, and also a property (restaurant-1) have not paid any rent (no records in rent table) should also be listed...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```
select p.id, p.propertyname, pt.typename
from properties p inner join property_types pt on (p.typeid = pt.id)
where not exists
(
   select 1
   from properties_rent
   where year = 2012
   and propertyid = p.id
)
```